# VSFTPD An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: vsftpd

I am trying to setup several ftp users, each with its own subfolder (so the user can see only he his root folder, and nothing else).

current issue is that on filezilla I am getting

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I tried all options of the FTP in Filezilla (TLS explicit or implicit). Error in all the options.

/etc/vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/ftpmain/ftp/$USER
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
pasv_address=123.123.123.123
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
```

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

the user1 folder looks like this (after chmod+chown):

```
/home/ftpmain/ftp/user1$ ll
total 12
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 Mar 18 19:17 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 18 19:09 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsftpd nogroup 4096 Mar 18 19:17 folder1/
```

Any idea?

### UPDATE

From what I am reading, this can be related to folder doesn't exist, or wrong permissions.
I added 'allow_writeable_chroot=YES' i the conf file.
I also added 'log_ftp_protocol=YES'.

This is the current log (/var/log/vsftpd.log):

```
Wed May  1 08:44:28 2019 [pid 2310] CONNECT: Client "111.111.111.111"
Wed May  1 08:44:28 2019 [pid 2310] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Wed May  1 08:44:28 2019 [pid 2310] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "AUTH TLS"
Wed May  1 08:44:28 2019 [pid 2310] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "234 Proceed with negotiation."
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2310] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "USER user1"
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2310] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "331 Please specify the password."
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2310] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "PASS <password>"
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2309] [user1] OK LOGIN: Client "111.111.111.111"
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "230 Login successful."
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "PBSZ 0"
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "200 PBSZ set to 0."
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "PROT P"
Wed May  1 08:44:29 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "200 PROT now Private."
Wed May  1 08:44:30 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "PWD"
Wed May  1 08:44:30 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "257 "/" is the current directory"
Wed May  1 08:44:30 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "TYPE I"
Wed May  1 08:44:30 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP response: Client "111.111.111.111", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Wed May  1 08:44:30 2019 [pid 2319] [user1] FTP command: Client "111.111.111.111", "PASV"
```

after chown for the 'user1' folder:

```
$ ll
dr-xr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Mar 18 19:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 ftpmain  ftpmain   4096 Mar 18 16:09 ../
dr-xr-xr-x 3 vsftpd    1002 4096 Mar 18 19:17 user1/
```

/home/ftpmain/ftp is owned by 'nobody:nogroup'

### UPDATE #2

current situation is that I made sure that I can connect to the FTP using plain FTP-active mode. For plain FTP-passive mode I am still getting an error:

```
Status: Resolving address of .....
Status: Connecting to 111.111.111.111:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address
Command:    PORT 10,0,0,15,253,199
Response:   500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  Connection closed by server
```

When trying with TLS, I am still getting the same `unexpected TLS packet was received` error, even after trying chmod on the user1 folder

```
 drwxrwx--- 3 vsftpd    1002 4096 May  1 10:58 user1/
```

Comment: yes. it was a typo. I edited it now

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270722

Comment: thanks. I made some changes according to what I read there, but still didn't find a way to make it work. I updated the question with what I found

Comment: It looks like your chroot directory has read and execute set for others - I think it's the problem, please try to change it to something like chmod 750 or 770, like `chmod 770 -R user1`

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately it didn't work. See update#2

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it to work.
Beside my debugging process which I outlined in the updates to the original question, here is what I did after.

For TLS to work, I recommend that you first make sure that passive mode is working without TLS. This is because from what I understand the encryption will prevent the server ip that is sent by the server to be received by the ftp client.

So first step, disable TLS by setting `ssl_enable=YES` in the conf file.

Passive mode requires additional ports. These are the lines that are related to that in the config file:

```
pasv_address=111.111.111.111
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
port_enable=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

You have to make sure that the passive ports are open! I was using EC2, so you need to open the ports in the security groups. In addition check ufw:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 20/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 990/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 9] 40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[10] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

With this I was able to connect using passive mode, and then enabling `ssl_enable=YES` just worked.

This final /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
connect_from_port_20=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES

nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/ftpmain/ftp/$USER
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
use_localtime=YES
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

pasv_address=111.111.111.111
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
port_enable=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed all the steps well explained in [this link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-vps/).

And then, yes I encountered similar error. So I followed the suggestion in [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139741/1165986) to first try to connect without TLS by commenting `ssl_enable=YES`.

However, this did not work (see following error):

```
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

**Until** I added this directive in the configuration file `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

However, I have done some searches and found that for security reasons, this option must *not* be set to `YES`:

In the [`vsftpd.conf` main page](https://man.linuxreviews.org/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html):

> allow_writeable_chroot
>
> Allow chroot()'ing a user to a directory writable by that user. Note that setting this to **YES is potentially dangerous**. For example, if the user creates an 'etc' directory in the new root directory, they could potentially trick the C library into loading a user-created configuration file from the /etc/ directory.

Check also [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/743949/vsftp-why-is-allow-writeable-chroot-yes-a-bad-idea).

As a reminder [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chroot) is an operation that changes the apparent root directory for the current running process and their children. A program that is run in such a modified environment cannot access files and commands outside that environmental directory tree. This modified environment is called a chroot jail.

So a good practice, is to set `allow_writeable_chroot=NO` and make an ftp directory which acts as chroot. Here is an example:

```
mkdir /home/ftpuser/ftpdirectory
chown -R ftpuser:ftpuser
chmod a-w /home/ftpuser
```

And finally in the config file `vsftpd.conf`:

```
user_sub_token=$USER 
local_root=/home/$USER/ftpdirectory
```